# How can I resolve a 'Windows Backend: Object has no attribute iso_path' error while installing with Wubi?

Tags: installation, windows, dual-boot, wubi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu using Wubi in Windows XP Professional SP3 32bit.  After running wubi I receive an installation error.

```
"Windows backend" object has no attribute 'iso_path' ....For more information, please see the log file:C:\documents and settings\rickh\locals settings\temp\wubi-11.10-rev241.log.
```

Log:

```
02-22 10:44 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished create_uninstaller
02-22 10:44 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running copy_installation_files...
02-22 10:44 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\DOCUME~1\RickH\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl70.tmp\data\custom-installation -> C:\ubuntu\install\custom-installation
02-22 10:44 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\DOCUME~1\RickH\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl70.tmp\winboot -> C:\ubuntu\winboot
02-22 10:44 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\DOCUME~1\RickH\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl70.tmp\data\images\Ubuntu.ico -> C:\ubuntu\Ubuntu.ico
02-22 10:44 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished copy_installation_files
02-22 10:44 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running get_iso...
02-22 10:44 DEBUG  TaskList: New task copy_file
02-22 10:44 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running copy_file...
02-22 10:46 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished copy_file
02-22 10:46 DEBUG  TaskList: New task check_iso
02-22 10:46 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running check_iso...
02-22 10:46 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Checking C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
02-22 10:46 DEBUG  Distro:   checking Ubuntu ISO C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
02-22 10:46 DEBUG  Distro:     wrong size: 2119696384 > 900000000
02-22 10:46 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished check_iso
02-22 10:46 ERROR  TaskList: 'WindowsBackend' object has no attribute 'iso_path'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 579, in get_iso
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 565, in use_iso
AttributeError: 'WindowsBackend' object has no attribute 'iso_path'
02-22 10:46 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
02-22 10:46 ERROR  root: 'WindowsBackend' object has no attribute 'iso_path'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 130, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 205, in run_cd_menu
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 120, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 579, in get_iso
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 565, in use_iso
AttributeError: 'WindowsBackend' object has no attribute 'iso_path'
02-22 10:46 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
```

Comment: It is difficult to tell what are you asking.

Comment: How are you trying to install Ubuntu?. Are you using a CD or a pendrive?.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?

Answer (score 2):

Wubi doesn't like the ISO size:

```
02-22 10:46 DEBUG  Distro:     wrong size: 2119696384 > 900000000
```

Wubi is designed to install using only a desktop CD ISO (not the DVD ISO) and there is a simplistic check on the size to ensure it's a CD. It has to be between 550MB and 850MB (more or less). You can burn a CD ISO to a DVD and it will work because the ISO doesn't increase in size, but if you create an Ubuntu USB with a CD ISO, Wubi copies the entire USB partition before checking the size. So if you're installing from a USB with a partition > ~850MB then it won't work. It's hard to know exactly since you haven't included more of the log.

In summary: what you've got there is not recognizable as an Ubuntu Desktop CD ISO (even if it is a valid one).

Solution:
Place wubi.exe and the desktop CD ISO (both from the same release) in the same directory and run wubi from there. Make sure you remove any other media (CDs, USBs) first. Or run wubi.exe standalone and it will download the image itself.